# Optimise a function with numerous conditions that depends on the previous row in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

| country_ID | ID | direction | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESP_1 | 0 | IN | 2021-02-28 |
| ENG | 0 | IN | 2021-03-03 |
| ENG | 0 | OUT | 2021-03-04 |
| ESP_2 | 0 | IN | 2021-03-05 |
| FRA | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-07 |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-09 |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-10 |
| ENG | 2 | IN | 2021-03-13 |

I have implemented the following functionality:

```
ef create_columns_analysis(df):  
    df['visit_ESP'] = 0
    df['visit_ENG'] = 0
    df['visit_FRA'] = 0
    list_ids = []
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i,'country_ID'] == 'ENG':
            country_ID_ENG(df, i, list_ids)
        else:
          # case country_ID = {FRA, ESP_1, ESP_2}
          # other methods not specified

    return df
```

For each row with a specific country_ID, a similarly structured function is applied.

I would like to optimise or simplify the code of the country_ID_ENG function. The country_ID_ENG function is defined as follows:

```
def country_ID_ENG(df, i, list_ids):
    # If it is the first time the ID is detected
    if df.loc[i,'ID'] not in list_ids:
        # It adds up to one visit regardless of the direction of the ID
        df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
        # Add the ID to the read list
        list_ids.append(df.loc[i, 'ID'])
        # Assigns the error column a start message
        df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:1'
    # If it is not the first time it detects that ID
    else:
        # Saves the information of the previous row
        prev_row = df.loc[i-1]
        # If the current row direction is 'IN'
        if df.loc[i,'direction'] == 'IN':
            # Add a visit
            df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
            # Behaviour dependent on the previous row
            # If the current row direction is 'IN' and previous row is 'IN' 
            if prev_row['direction'] == 'IN':
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'FRA':
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:0'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['ESP_1','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:2'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:3'   
            # If the current row direction is 'IN' and previous row is 'OUT' 
            else:
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG':
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:0'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['FRA','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:4'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:5'    
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ESP'] = 1
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
        # If the current row direction is 'OUT'
        else:
            # If the current row direction is 'OUT' and previous row is 'IN' 
            if prev_row['direction'] == 'IN':
                # If it detects an output before an input of the same 'country_ID', 
                # it calculates the visit time
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG':
                    df.loc[i,'mean_time'] = df.loc[i,'date']-prev_row['date']
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:0'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['ESP_1','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:6'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:7'    
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
            # If the current row direction is 'OUT' and previous row is 'OUT' 
            else:
                df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG':
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:8'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['FRA','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:9'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:10'  
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ESP'] = 1
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
```

The above function uses the information from the current row and the previous row (if any) to create new columns for visit_ENG, visit_ESP, visit_FRA, mean_time and error.

For the example dataframe the function, applying the function country_ID_ENG to rows whose country_ID is equal to ENG, should return the following result:

| country_ID | ID | direction | date | visit_ENG | visit_FRA | visit_ESP | mean_time | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESP_1 | 0 | IN | 2021-02-28 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NaN | NaN |
| ENG | 0 | IN | 2021-03-03 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:2 |
| ENG | 0 | OUT | 2021-03-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 days | ERROR:0 |
| ESP_2 | 0 | IN | 2021-03-05 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NaN | NaN |
| FRA | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-07 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NaN | NaN |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-09 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:9 |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:8 |
| ENG | 2 | IN | 2021-03-13 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:1 |

The function is very long, and the other functions for rows with country_ID equal to ESP or FRA will have the same complexity. I would like you to help me to simplify or optimise the code of this function to also take it into account when defining the country_ID_ESP and country_ID_FRA functions. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Good question, but the title at the moment is quite generic - what is your code actually _for_; that's what you should title your question in general

Comment: @Greedo edited! thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: What is the logic behind the errors.  I'm trying to come up with a way to index the errors with a condition. why is `prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG'` and `prev_row['country_ID'] == 'FRA'` an `ERROR:0`.

Comment: This won't actually run. Your first `else` can't only have a comment: Python requires at least a `pass`.

Comment: Your example output does not match what your code does. Assuming that `-` means NaN/`None`, your first row has zeros in `visit_ESP`, `visit_ENG` and `visit_FRA`, but you've shown `-`.

Comment: Further, your actual and demonstrated `visit_FRA` do not match. The actual column has no ones.

Comment: Your edit didn't really help. Your output is full of discrepancies. I encourage you to verbatim copy and paste and check the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per pandas [iteration](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration) guidance

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect!

### suggested

```py
from typing import Iterable, Tuple
import pandas as pd

COLS = ['country_ID',   'ID',   'direction', 'date']


DATA = [['ESP_1', 0, 'IN', '2021-02-28'],
        ['ENG', 0, 'IN', '2021-03-03'],
        ['ENG', 0, 'OUT', '2021-03-04'],
        ['ESP_2', 0, 'IN', '2021-03-05'],
        ['FRA', 1, 'OUT', '2021-03-07'],
        ['ENG', 1, 'OUT', '2021-03-09'],
        ['ENG', 1, 'OUT', '2021-03-10'],
        ['ENG', 2, 'IN', '2021-03-13']]



def both_in(country_id: str):
    """where both condtions were `IN`"""
    esp, eng, fra = (0, 0, 0)
    if country_id == 'FRA':
        error_code = 0
    elif country_id in ('ESP_1', 'ESP_2'):
        error_code = 2
        fra = 1
    else:
        error_code = 3

    return (esp, eng, fra, f'ERROR:{error_code}')


def both_out(country_id: str):
    """where both contionds were `OUT`"""
    esp, eng, fra = (0, 1, 0)

    if country_id == 'ENG':
        error_code = 8
    elif country_id in ('FRA', 'ESP_2'):
        error_code = 9
        fra = 1
    else:
        error_code = 10
        esp, fra = 1, 1

    return (esp, eng, fra, f'ERROR:{error_code}')


def in_out(country_id: str):
    """where current was IN and previous was OUT"""
    esp, eng, fra = (0, 0, 0)

    if country_id == 'ENG':
        error_code = 0

    elif country_id in ('FRA', 'ESP_2'):
        error_code = 4
        fra = 1

    else:
        error_code = 5
        esp = 1
        fra = 1

    return (esp, eng, fra, f'ERROR:{error_code}')


def out_in(country_id: str):
    """where current was `OUT` and previous was `IN`"""
    esp, eng, fra = (0, 0, 0)
    if country_id == 'ENG':
        error_code = 0

    elif country_id in ('ESP_1', 'ESP_2'):
        error_code = 6
        eng, fra = 1, 1
    else:
        error_code = 7
        eng = 1

    return (esp, eng, fra, f'ERROR:{error_code}')


def create_columns_analysis(df: pd.DataFrame)->Iterable[Tuple[int,int,int,str,pd.Timestamp]]:
    """create_columns_analysis"""

    # in your logic there are 4 potential driving conditions based on the direction
    # of the current row and the previous row.  so we'll make a dictionary that we can
    # index and call the associated functions.
    direction = {
        ('IN', 'IN'): both_in,
        ('OUT', 'OUT'): both_out,
        ('IN', 'OUT'): in_out,
        ('OUT', 'IN'): out_in,
    }
    # to align the direction slice
    # - the last row
    # - the first row
    # - and zip them together
    def iter_countires():
        """yields a (ESP,ENG,FRA,ERROR,MEAN_TIME)"""
        list_ids = []

        # because we sliced the first row from the loop yield that value first
        def first_row(country_id):
            if country_id == 'ENG':
                return (0, 1, 0, 'ERROR:1', pd.NA)
            return (0, 0, 0, 'ERROR:1', pd.NA)

        yield first_row(df['country_ID'][0])

        for previous, current in zip(df[:-1].itertuples(), df[1:].itertuples()):
            time_delta = current.date-previous.date
            # If it is the first time the ID is detected
            if current.country_ID == 'ENG' and current.ID not in list_ids:
                list_ids.append(current.ID)
                yield (0, 1, 0, 'ERROR:1', time_delta)

            elif current.country_ID == 'ENG':
                # indexing our dict with the ('IN','OUT') to get the function
                conditional_func = (
                    direction[(previous.direction, current.direction)])
                # call the function and pass the previous.country_ID as thats the only var it relies on
                # unpack thoes values and tack on the timedelta
                yield (*conditional_func(previous.country_ID), time_delta)

            else:
                # you could create a different conditional func dict if you wanted to
                # handle country_ID logic differently
                yield (0, 0, 0, pd.NA, pd.NA)


    return iter_countires()



def start():
    """start"""
    df = pd.DataFrame(DATA, columns=COLS)

    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

    df[['visit_ESP', 'visit_ENG', 'visit_FRA', 'error', 'mean_time']]=(
        tuple(create_columns_analysis(df)))

    print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

### result

```
  country_ID  ID direction       date visit_ESP visit_ENG visit_FRA    error        mean_time
0      ESP_1   0        IN 2021-02-28         0         0         0  ERROR:1             <NA>
1        ENG   0        IN 2021-03-03         0         1         0  ERROR:1  3 days 00:00:00
2        ENG   0       OUT 2021-03-04         0         0         0  ERROR:0  1 days 00:00:00
3      ESP_2   0        IN 2021-03-05         0         0         0     <NA>             <NA>
4        FRA   1       OUT 2021-03-07         0         0         0     <NA>             <NA>
5        ENG   1       OUT 2021-03-09         0         1         0  ERROR:1  2 days 00:00:00
6        ENG   1       OUT 2021-03-10         0         1         0  ERROR:8  1 days 00:00:00
7        ENG   2        IN 2021-03-13         0         1         0  ERROR:1  3 days 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Just a note, the mean_time column only has a value other than NaN if, in this case, the current row is 'OUT' and the previous row is 'IN' and both have country_ID == ENG.